# SpaCy vs AllenNLP?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, spacy, allennlp

I have used a little of both [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) and [allenNLP](https://allennlp.org/) in my NLP projects. I like them both as they work very well with [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) (my DL framework choice!). But, I still cannot decide which one to master in a long term so that I can increase the pace of my NLP projects in future.
Can someone please share their experience or suggest the differences between these 2 libraries or pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spaCy [used to recommended](https://web.archive.org/web/20200108144536/https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures/#comparison-usage) (archive link) that you use spaCy when you want production-grade performance but don't need to customize your architecture.  They recommended that you use allenNLP when you want to explore different architectures or use the state-of-the-art models.  They recommended against using allenNLP for production, though.

Since spaCy 3.0, they [now recommend](https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures#comparison-usage) (live link) that you can also use spaCy for customized and state-of-the-art models. They still don't recommend spaCy for language generation models or for active research.